# How to set concurrency level in concurrentHashMap in java

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Please tell me how to set concurrency level in ConcurrentHashMap in java? What impact does it have if the level is set too high or too low? How does it work internally?

Answer (score 2):

ConcurrentHashMap  constructor

```
 public ConcurrentHashMap(int initialCapacity,
                             float loadFactor, int concurrencyLevel) {
```

You can very well define the concurrency level as desired by you.
Regarding your second question.
Here is the javadoc comment from ConncurrentHashMap (java 1.6)

```
 * Ideally, you should choose a value to accommodate as many
 * threads as will ever concurrently modify the table. Using a
 * significantly higher value than you need can waste space and time,
 * and a significantly lower value can lead to thread contention.
```

So ideally if you don't know things like how big the map could become or how many thread will be accessing the map , Better use default values of concurrency (which is currently 16).

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java

Hope its help !

Comment: However ConcurrencyLevel is internally bounded by 65536(max concurrency)

Comment: How higher concurrencyLevel value can waste space? I mean if I keep initialCapacity as 16 and concurrencyLevel as 20 and loadfactor as 0.75f. then what would be Segment Array size? I am missing something basic but not cleared about it.